# Error Variable Undefined when I Add a parameter in my action form

Tags: laravel, forms, parameters, laravel-blade

I'm trying to pass the parameter that I have in my route file, into my form.
And when I do it, the error of **Undefined Variable** appears

```
<form action="{{route('capitulos_destroy_multiple',$curso)}}" method="POST" id="eliminar-multiples">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Here is my route:

```
   Route::post('destroy_multiple/{curso}','CapitulosController@destroy_multiple')->name('capitulos_destroy_multiple');
```

And Here is my controller, that returns that exact variable:

public function destroy_multiple(Request $request,$curso)
{

```
return redirect('administrador/capitulos/index/'.$curso);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your route should be called the following way:

{{route('capitulos_destroy_multiple',['curso'=>$curso])}}

Feel free to refer to Laravel manual: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes

```
Route::get('user/{id}/profile', function ($id) {
    //
})->name('profile');

$url = route('profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

Hope it helps.